# Can I change direction of ROC?

Tags: modeling, roc, auc

I made a model, and I wanted to get AUC with independent test set.
So I got AUC which is  0.3.

In many writings, high AUC(1-0.3) can appear if i change 'direction'argument of roc function.

(i understand this comment BUT)

I'm  thinking about this ; 
AUC=0.3 means that 
model which was made by training set could't predict test set .
Changing direction simply give high AUC, but isn't right principally.

Can I change dirrection of roc ? I

Comment: Wait, what was the AUC on your training set? Was the direction different than on the test set?